# Will Tom now be able to hear and communicate with the dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, stir-of-echoes

Re: the end of *Stir of Echoes*, will Tom (Kevin Bacon) now be able to hear and communicate with the dead just as his son is able to do, or, was it just a one time deal that was brought on by Maggie's sister hypnotizing him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was a one-time connection - he was in the right place at the right time and the hypnosis just opened a channel the girl could use to reach him. Reason why - he only sees the one girl; a city the size and age of Philadelphia, if he has been able to see more ghosts he certainly would have done so.